# Uploading to blob container when pushing to azure git repo

Tags: git, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I have a node.js application in Azure. Is it possible to upload files from a particular folder to the blob container when I do a git push to the azure git repo ("git push azure master").

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the current answer to this is 'no'.  Pushing to git simply publishes to the target site bound to that repository and cannot snap out content and push it to blob storage (which is what I assume you mean).  Would be a nice feature though to target the location of a publish.

Comment: So, we cannot add any scripting in Azure, for this to happen?

Comment: Not using the auto-publish git repositories hosted on Azure.  You'd probably need to build out your own server running TeamCity or similar and then write or use an extension to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: 2020: look at Github actions.